# PipEnv: How to handle locally installed .whl packages

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm using PipEnv to set up a project, and some packages I'm needing to install from precompiled binaries. In a previous project I just pipenv installed the .whl files from some local folder into my environment, but this seems to cause issues with the lock file throwing an error if someone else tries to install from the repository since the pipfile tracks the local path. What are best practices for this? Should I create a packages repository as part of the project and install from that?

Comment: Why not set up a [private PyPI index](https://gist.github.com/Jaza/fcea493dd0ba6ebf09d3) to serve those wheels?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I think this could reasonably be a viable solution, especially if I was creating these .whl files myself. But given that I'm working with packages that are already published (and downloaded from [this wonderful resource](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)), it feels unnecessary to create a wrapper repository. What would the benefits of this be compared to storing the .whl files in the project itself?

Comment: That wonderful resource does not provide a PyPI compatible index. Defining your own index would save everyone from having to download the wheels manually.

Comment: And if you are working with team members that do not use Windows, you can save those members from having to download your wheel files entirely.

Comment: Ah, alternative: install the direct URL for the wheel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should set up a private PyPI index server, and [configure Pipenv to use that server](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/advanced/#specifying-package-indexes).

Setting up a private PyPI server is trivial with a project like [`pypiserver`](https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/):

```
$ mkdir private_pypi && cd private_pypi
$ pipenv install   # create pipenv files
$ pipenv install pypiserver
$ mkdir packages
$ pipenv run pypi-server -p 8080 ./packages &
```

and put your wheels into their `projectname` subdirectry of the `packages` directory, or use `twine` to publish your package to the server.

Then add a `[[source]]` section in your projects `Pipfile` to point to the server (the url to use ends in `/simple`, so `http://hostname:8080/simple`):

```
[[source]]
url = "http://hostname:8080/simple"
verify_ssl = false
name = "some_logical_name"
```

You can use the default `name = "pypi"` section as a guide.

In the `[packages]` section, specify the index to use for those private wheels:

```
[packages]
wheel1 = {version="*", index="some_logical_name"}
wheel2 = {version="0.41.1", index="some_logical_name"}
some_public_project = "*"
```

Again, you can explicitly name any of the named indices, including `index="pypi"`. Not adding a `index="..."` restriction lets `Pipenv` search all indexes for possible distributions.

For binary wheels published outside of an index (such as [those built by Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)), you could consider just installing the full wheel URL:

```
pipenv install https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/l8ulg3xw/aiohttp-3.3.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

This does force everyone using your Pipfile to a specific platform.

Comment: This is an excellent response, and thank you for providing multiple options and examples. Minor side question, how did you get the download link from Gohlke's site? Trying to copy link path doesn't seem to work for me (I get `;`)

Comment: I used the developer console; in the network tab a new entry appears when you click a link, as the browser asks where to save the file. I took the URL from that.

Comment: `pipenv run pypi-server -p 8080 ./packages &` should be `--port=8080` on newer versions. '-p' is no longer recognized as an option. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @ChrisHuang-Leaver: no, both `-p 8080` and `--port=8080` work. Something may be wrong on your side, or there could, perhaps, be a bug, but the [source code of the project](https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver/blob/47d6efe1967706caf584cfbd220ea61d79e6e62c/pypiserver/__main__.py#L221-L227) shows `-p` is still supported.

Comment: Is there an alternative using a local path?

Comment: @EricBurel: this answer was written specifically because a local path would not work for a project shared with others. If you have local wheel files, you can already install them without the need for a local index server.